# PL SQL Procedure from Trigger

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I created procedure GETDEL that select name from students , but when i try to call this procedure in trigger it says i gave wrong types of argument to call

I have been trying to pass (records) or (records OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) as a argument but it dont works

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GETDEL(records OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS 
BEGIN
  OPEN records FOR
    SELECT name FROM  students;
END GETDEL;
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER After_delete_student
AFTER DELETE ON TABLE2
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  rec sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
  GETDELCZL();
END;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your procedure contains a single parameter and, even though it's an out parameter, the calling procedure is responsible the defining it.

```
create or replace 
trigger after_delete_student
after delete 
 on table2
 for each row 
declare
    result_rec sys_refcursor;
begin 
    getdel(result_rec);
end;
```